Get changes made to single instances of repeating events
I'm trying to access the events in Calendar.app from AppleScript. It seems I can't retrieve any information about instances of repeating events that have been changed. When reading all events of a calendar, repeating events are returned as a single item without any information about instances that have been changed.
To test this, I've create a new calendar with a single event that repeats daily at 18:00. Then I changed the time and summary of the instance on the 15th:

I'm using this code to read all events:
tell application "Calendar"
    properties of events of calendar "Todo"
end tell    

What I get is a reponse with a single entry:
{
    {
        id:"C26C7A0F-0C6D-491C-99B9-AC117430B078",
        recurrence:"FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1",
        stamp date:date "2024-04-13 at 13:28:57",
        class:event,
        url:missing value,
        end date:date "2024-04-13 at 19:00:00",
        excluded dates:{},
        description:"",
        summary:"Test",
        location:missing value,
        allday event:false,
        start date:date "2024-04-13 at 18:00:00",
        sequence:1,
        status:confirmed
    }
}

Is there any way to get information about instances that have been changed, i.e. the instance with summary "I changed this!" in the example above?
